# Scroll not working using angularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, scroll

I have live streaming using socket.io , i have set max-height for window to implement scroll bar , but i noticed after reaching to certain point scroll bar does not work and does not display messages, I can see messages are being logged into `event` but vertical scroll bar is not extending anymore. Any idea how i can fix this issue ?

main.html

```
<div class="panel-body display-logs" scroll-bottom="event">
                <ul style="list-style: none;">
                    <li ng-repeat="message in event | limitTo:1000" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span>{{message.value}}</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

main.css

```
.display-logs {
    min-height: 700px;
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.event = [];     
socket.on('StConsumer',function (data) {
            var obj = {
                file:$scope.filename,
                data:data
            }
            getBytesForBuffer(data);
           // $scope.event.push(data);
           safelyAdd({
                id:$scope.event.length,
                value: data
            });

            if(sendMessageFlag === true) {
                getByteLen(data);
                $scope.progressBarFlag = true;
                Bufferlimit = $scope.maxBytes;
                return  sendMessageToFile(obj);

            }
        });

  function safelyAdd(element){
          if(totalRecieved > Bufferlimit){
             $scope.event =[];//reset array if max size reached..
              totalRecieved = 0;
        }
          $scope.event.push(element); //then push new item..
          console.log('TotalRecievedBytes',totalRecieved)
        }
```

Comment: Please share more details, as it is very basic CSS property and If we try it with HTML, it works fine, so to rectify the issue, you need you share more details

Comment: I added controller as well, we have live streaming 5k messages per minute at some point during loading data scroll bar does not work and doesnt display latest messages

Comment: If you do inspect element, in that case, all that messages(which are actualy not showing on screen) shows there(Developer console) or not?

Comment: yes those are showing in console , so i am printing `$scope.event` and i see messages are rolling there

Comment: Sorry, Not by the console.log, are they showing in HTML when we check it by inspect element? I know it is not showing on screen, but just asking whether they are visible in developer inspect element part or not

Comment: you mean when we inspect element it does not show binding to $scope

Comment: I mean like, there might be an problem with $scope binding, at some time. So please check whether it is binding to page or not?